# 16.04 Lts doesn't contain auto run and wubi file

Tags: 16.04, wubi

I have downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 from its website through a torrent, but I am unable to install it because it doesn't contain auto run and wubi files. What to do now?

Comment: Do you now have the ISO?

Comment: Yes i have iso as it is.

Comment: What Operating System do you currently run?

Comment: I am running windows 10 now

Comment: You have to install ubuntu as a dual boot, wubi is no longer supported and was only meant to be used for testing, not for permanent use.

Comment: Please tell me the procedure to install as dual boot!!!!

Comment: Wubi is not necessary for installing. But there are [community supported versions](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases), if you think you need Wubi. see [Wubi info](http://askubuntu.com/tags/wubi/info)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the normal installation procedure:

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

or specifically for dual boot with Windows 8 or later and Ubuntu 15.10 or later:

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html

This will install it for you.

Comment: Normal installation not working as it says usb drive has no system to install :( :( :(

Comment: Please open a new question for this. This is a entirely new issue.

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04 and Higher, Use Wubi by Hakuna Matata To Install Wubi on Windows Laptop/Computers without using a USB Stick.

**Wubi Hakuna Matata download from the wiki: [https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki]**

If you want to do other Linux OS, you can use Unetbootin or Rufus